# approximating functions via a piecewise combination of linear and constant functions

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, linear-approximation, simple-functions

I am curious if anyone has encountered any literature on approximating functions via a piecewise combination of linear and constant functions.

I have seen a couple of papers which use piecewise constant functions only or piecewise linear functions only but not a combination of both.

Has anyone seen any published work on what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean some pieces would be approximated by constant functions and the rest by linear functions? A linear function $f(x) = a + b x$ can do everything a constant function $f(x) = a$ can do and more. So the best approximation of a given function would usually have no constant function pieces at all.

Comment: @Tomas Jorovic: If any of the answers below were helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) them. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$ can be approximated using such an interpolation:

Partition $[a,b]$ into $[a=x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n=b]$, and then your approximation will be given by:

$$f^*(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x_k),  & \text{if $x=x_k$} \\
y_k, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

with $y_k$ satisfying, for $0\le k\le n-1$:

$$\frac{f(x_k)-f(x_{k+1})}{x_k-x_{k+1}}=\frac{y_k-f(x_k)}{x-x_k}$$

That's why it is called a "linear" interpolation.

Note that, for all $x\in[a,b]$:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^*(x)=f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

In this context, linear functions are of the form $a\,x+b$. Thus, constant functions are a particular case of linear functions when $a=0$. This type of approximation is called linear interpolation.